# About the javascript function's inaccessbility in an User Control from other user control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Now the weird thing is I have a user control UserControl1 in which I put some JavaScrdipt logic there, and I have another user control UserControl2 and I registered both in the page called Page1.aspx.

I would like to call the JavaScript function resided in UserControl1 from UserControl2, however, I got an error saying the function is not defined. I think both user controls are loaded before I use them then I think the JavaScript function can been seen anyway in that page.

And what is the loading step for aspx page and JavaScript code?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have such reuse of java script, then put those script in a seperate .js file and include the file on both control and set cachable. only on copy of the file will be downloaded by the client and used by both controls.